# Запуск java-приложения с внешними библиотеками

Tags: jar, java

Есть java-исходник, подключающийся к MsSQL.
Компилируется нормально. В условиях дебагера запускается и отрабатывает.

При упаковке его в jar (IDEA 11), да и без такого, выдаёт при запуске classNotFound на строчке

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Командная строка запуска:

```
java myapp -classpath "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib\sqljdbc4.jar"
```

или

```
java -jar myapp.jar -classpath "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib\sqljdbc4.jar"
```

Вариант с sqljdbc.jar вместо, sqljdbc4.jar тоже не канает. Сами библиотеки по указанному пути есть и в отладочном варианте работают.

Подскажите, куда вправлять мозг?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратите внимание на опцию `-jar` в [описании команды java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> When you use this option, the JAR file
> is the source of all user classes, and
> other user class path settings are
> ignored.

Таким образом вы или пакуете `sqljdbc4.jar` вместе с вашим кодом, либо запускаете main-класс вручную:

```
java -classpath "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib\sqljdbc4.jar";myapp.jar com.example.Main
```

Answer (score 3):

В манифесте, необходимо, указать относительные пути к библиотекам, относительно jar-файла

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Main-Class:   
Class-Path: lib/mylib.jar
```

Comment: И вам тоже спасибо!

Жаль нельзя оба правильными отметить...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно будет полезно. Если запускается класс вне jar, и нужно подключить внешнюю библиотеку, используется такая строка запуска:

`java -classpath sqljdbc4.jar;./ MyAppClass`

Comment: Мне это помогло при запуске класса с отельной jar библиотекой